# Missing connection for port 'v1'

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim

I'm working on a systemVerilog code, where a lookup value is being compared to 8 registers of the same bit size, it should give valid 1 if one of the registers matches the the lookup val. everything compiles but it gives several warnings stating "Missing connection for port 'v1'" and I'm not sure how to resolve this issue

code below with a simple testbench

```
module V(
input logic [3:0] A,B,
output logic valid);

  logic xnor_3, xnor_2, xnor_1, xnor_0, and_0;
  
  assign xnor_3 = ~(A[3] ^ B[3]);
  assign xnor_2 = ~(A[2] ^ B[2]);
  assign xnor_1 = ~(A[1] ^ B[1]);
  assign xnor_0 = ~(A[0] ^ B[0]);
  assign and_0 = xnor_1 & xnor_0 & xnor_2 & xnor_3 ;
  assign valid = and_0 ;
  
endmodule

module Vt(
input logic[3:0] D_lookup,
input logic[3:0] r0,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,
output logic v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, Valid);

  V vt0(D_lookup,r0,v0);
  V vt1(D_lookup,r1,v1);
  V vt2(D_lookup,r2,v2);
  V vt3(D_lookup,r3,v3);
  V vt4(D_lookup,r4,v4);
  V vt5(D_lookup,r5,v5);
  V vt6(D_lookup,r6,v6);
  V vt7(D_lookup,r7,v7);

  assign Valid = v0 || v1 || v2 || v3 || v4 || v5 || v6 || v7;
endmodule

module tb_V();
logic[3:0] D_lookup;
logic[3:0] r0,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7;
Vt dut(D_lookup,r0,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,Valid);
initial begin
D_lookup = 4'b1010;
r0 = 4'b1000;
r1 = 4'b1001;
r2 = 4'b1010;
r3 = 4'b1011;
r4 = 4'b1100;
r5 = 4'b1101;
r6 = 4'b1110;
r7 = 4'b1111; 
#10;
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have helped if you posted and read the exact error message you are getting

```
# ** Warning: (vsim-2685) [TFMPC] - Too few port connections for 'dut'.  Expected 18, found 10.
#    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /tb_V/dut File: testbench.sv Line: 36
# ** Warning: (vsim-3722) testbench.sv(36): [TFMPC] - Missing connection for port 'v1'.
# ** Warning: (vsim-3722) testbench.sv(36): [TFMPC] - Missing connection for port 'v2'.
# ** Warning: (vsim-3722) testbench.sv(36): [TFMPC] - Missing connection for port 'v3'.
# ** Warning: (vsim-3722) testbench.sv(36): [TFMPC] - Missing connection for port 'v4'.
# ** Warning: (vsim-3722) testbench.sv(36): [TFMPC] - Missing connection for port 'v5'.
# ** Warning: (vsim-3722) testbench.sv(36): [TFMPC] - Missing connection for port 'v6'.
# ** Warning: (vsim-3722) testbench.sv(36): [TFMPC] - Missing connection for port 'v7'.
# ** Warning: (vsim-3722) testbench.sv(36): [TFMPC] - Missing connection for port 'Valid'.
```

So it seems you are missing all of the output port connections to your Vt module. All you need to do is add them. You don't even have to declare them separately; the will be implicitly declared as 1-bit wires.

```
  Vt dut(D_lookup,r0,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,
     v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, Valid );
```